# Failed to initialize joint_names. Aborting

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, joint-states, robot-description, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i am using the [staubli industrial robot driver](https://github.com/ros-industrial/staubli_experimental/tree/kinetic-devel/staubli_val3_driver). In the past it was working perfectly fine but this morning I got the following error message, when I tried launching the driver:

```
[ERROR] [1553757665.697264466]: Cannot find user-specified joint names. Tried ROS parameter 'controller_joint_names' and the URDF in 'robot_description'.
[ERROR] [1553757665.697285349]: Failed to initialize joint_names.
[ERROR] [1553757665.698784717]: Cannot find user-specified joint names. Tried ROS parameter 'controller_joint_names' and the URDF in 'robot_description'.
[ERROR] [1553757665.698798510]: Failed to initialize joint_names.  Aborting
[ERROR] [1553757665.699190014]: Cannot find user-specified joint names. Tried ROS parameter 'controller_joint_names' and the URDF in 'robot_description'.
[ERROR] [1553757665.699215342]: Failed to initialize joint_names.  Aborting
```

I have not really changed any kind of settings nor have I changed the content of the package itself. Any idea, where this error comes from?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319787/failed-to-initialize-joint_names.--aborting/) by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2019-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I really do not know why, but it works again. Really have no explenation for that error.
Will close this now.

---

Originally posted by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) with karma: 143 on 2019-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-28**:
This error is printed whenever the `industrial_robot` client cannot find the required parameters. It could be that your application was in an inconsistent state for some reason. Restarting (especially the master) could resolve such situations.